# Reactjs promise.all order of calls

Tags: reactjs, promise

I'm trying to fetch the `studentDataPromise` before `fetchLoansPromise` since it depends on the data `studentDataPromise` returns.

This is my current code:

```
Promise.all([studentDataPromise, fetchclassesPromise, fetchLoansPromise])
        .then(() => {
            toggleIsReady();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error);
        });
```

This is the current order of events:

1. `toggleIsReady` initially set to false, but is now true.
2. `fetchLoansPromise` - can’t fetch it doesn’t have the `studentDataPromise` fetched
3. `studentDataPromise`- fetches it correctly
4. `toggleIsReady` - Is now set to false
5. `fetchclassesPromise` - fetches it correctly

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `fetchLoansPromise` requires `studentDataPromise` to have resolved, why are you using `Promise.all` to run them *in parallel*?

Comment: Don't use `Promise.all` if you want one before the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how I solved it, Now 'fetchStudentData' is resolved before 'fetchLoansPromise'.

```
    let studentDataPromise = null;
    let fetchClassesPromise = null;
    let fetchLoansPromise = null;
```

```
    useEffect(() => {
        studentDataPromise = fetchStudentData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchClassesPromise = fetchClasses();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchLoansPromise = resolveStudentDataPromise();
    }, []);
```

```
    async function resolveStudentDataPromise() {
        await Promise.all([studentDataPromise]);
        fetchLoans();
    }

    Promise.all([studentDataPromise, fetchClassesPromise, fetchLoansPromise])
        .then(() => {
            toggleIsReady();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error);
        });
```

> Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all()` gets executed when all the promises you pass in resolve. That means you don't have guarantee that your `studentDataPromise` gets resolved before `fetchLoanPromise`. I recommend having a glance here [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

The easy way around it would be to use `.then()` once the promise resolves. This could look like so:

```
let studentDataPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  /**
   * 
   * 
   * **/
   reject(/**Something goes here**/)

  /**
   * Some Code here
   * 
   */
  resolve(/**Something goes here**/)

})

studentDataPromise
  .then((/**Whatever you return from resolve()**/) => {
    // Here you can call your fetchLoansPromise
    fetchLoansPromise
      .then(() => {
        /*** ***/
      })
  })
```

Or even more eleganty, with using `async/await`:

```
let studentDataPromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    /**
     * 
     * **/

     resolve()

  })
}


let someAsyncFunction = async () => {
  try {
    let studentData = await studentDataPromise()
    // Here you are guaranteed that your promise resolved
    // And you can call your other function
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
}
```

In either way you have to make sure that your first promise resolves, then you can your other functions. `Promise.all()` is great when you want to make sure that something happens after all your promises (which you pass on) get resolved. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Call `studentDataPromise` before other promisses.

```
studentDataPromise().then((data) => {
  Promise.all([fetchclassesPromise, fetchLoansPromise])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
Promise.all([studentDataPromise, fetchclassesPromise])
    .then(([studentData, classesData]) => fetchLoans(studentData))
    .then(() => toggleIsReady())
    .catch(error => {
        // handle exception
    });
```

Or using async await:

```
try {
    const [studentData, classesData] = await Promise.all([studentDataPromise, fetchclassesPromise]);
    const loansData = await fetchLoans(studentData);
    toggleIsRead();
} catch (e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Where `fetchLoans` would return a `fetchLoansPromise`.