# Reactjs promise.all

Tags: reactjs, promise

> Im having trouble getting 'studentDataPromise' to resolve before 'fetchLoansPromise'. I need to fetch the students data to be able to fetch the loans....any idea to what my error is?

currently

1. toggleIsReady() is called and set to true
2. fetchLoans() is called but since it relies on the students data its
   not fetching
3. fetchStudentData() is called and fetches correctly
4. fetchClasses() is called and fetches correctly

```
    let studentDataPromise = null;
    let fetchClassesPromise = null;
    let fetchLoansPromise = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        studentDataPromise = fetchStudentData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchClassesPromise = fetchClasses();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchLoansPromise = fetchLoans();
    }, []);

    /**
     * resolves promises and toggles isReady
     * action to true
     */


    Promise.all([studentDataPromise, fetchClassesPromise])
        .then(() => fetchLoansPromise)
        .then(() => toggleIsReady())
        .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error);
        });
```

Comment: the useEffect is by default executed on every render. the fetchStudentData & the others are not where the problem is. The problem im experiencing is that the order of events isnt reflected in the promise .all function i have.

Comment: You need to wait for both `studentData` and `fetchClasses` before *starting* `fetchLoans`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*need the promise to resolve [at a certain time]*"? You are *calling* all these functions immediately. If you want one of them to wait, put the *function call* inside the `then` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502465/11119825

see this post, this is now I solved it. Thanks to everyone !

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you should do something like this:

```
    const [student, setStudent] = useState({});
    const [classes, setClasses] = useState([]);
    const [loans, setLoans] = useState([]);
    useEffect(async () => {
        const studentData = await fetchStudentData();
        const fetchClasses = await fetchClasses();
        const fetchLoans = await fetchLoans();
        await toggleIsReady();
    }, []);
```